# The triple of a surface and his meaning

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I am working with an introduction book into differential geometry and there I got stucked at that point: Let $S \subset \Bbb R^3$ denote surface and $\phi: U \subset \Bbb R^2 \to S$ be a parametrization of $S$. Furthermore denote by $N$ the Gauss map of $\phi(U)$. We can now observe the triple $(\partial_1,\partial_2,N \circ \phi)$ as a base of $\Bbb R^3$. So we can express any vector of $\Bbb R^3$ as a linear combination of these vectors. So in particular there exists functions $\Gamma^k_{ij}, h_{ij}, a_{ij}$ s.t.
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=\Gamma^1_{ij}\partial_1 + \Gamma^2_{ij}\partial_2 + h_{ij}N $$
and
$$\frac{\partial (N \circ \phi)}{\partial x_j}=a_{1j}\partial_1 +a_{2j}\partial_2$$
The key point is here that we already know some of these functions. My question is now, why we have for example
$$h_{11}=e$$
I mean, why we have that $h_{11}= \langle N,\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_1^2}\rangle$? I don't the reason, why the scalar product comes into the game....

A second question is also for the $a_{ij}$'s. We have that $\frac{\partial (N \circ \phi)}{\partial x_i}= dN_p(\partial_i)$. But how can we now conclude that these are the components of the matrix $A$ that represents $dN_p$ with the respect to the basis $\{\partial_1,\partial_2\}$?

Many thanks for some help!

Comment: Your very first equation is wrong. The right-hand side should be $\Gamma^1_{ij}\partial_1 + \Gamma^2_{ij}\partial_2 + h_{ij}N$. A vector needs to equal a vector. Now, how do you find $h_{11}$? You should also review how you represent a linear map by a matrix when you have selected a basis.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo! A hint would be nice, since exactly there I am blocked... How can I find now $h_{11}$?

Comment: "Triple" is probably a better name than "triad"...

Comment: Did you calculate the inner product? Differential geometry is all about that.

Comment: Alright the first question is clear now... I am sorry, don't saw it! But the second one is still open

Comment: I answered that. Look at your basic linear algebra course.